# Lightning damage, Should I flash the Mobo

Tags: windows-7, laptop, bios

I was using a laptop on a raining day, and it got fired!
 Lightning struck, i got a shock, but temporarily without any fatal incidence.

> Compaq presario CQ61 aka insyde

but my laptop was affected, it was plugged in when i was using it.
 when i tried to boot some days later, i got an error message

```
Serial Number:  (empty- nothing is shown)
UUID Number is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Product Configuration ID:  00000000000000000
Factory installed OS:  non-vista
```

presently, the laptop boots up,but stops at the win7 logo with the progressbar. I tried to format, still stops there, i thought of doing a bios update, but need your imputes

Comment: So, was the power brick on a surge protector?

Answer (score 1):

1) Warranty is most likely void. BUT it might be covered by your householders' insurance.

2) At the moment, your machine is a brick. Flashing a BIOS won't make more bricked.

3) But I don't think it'll work. Your laptop forgot its serial number, model, what ever the factory flashed into it. Flashing a BIOS won't change this.